# How to login to real time company hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, hadoop2

I am new to hadoop environment. I was joined in a company and was given KT and required documents for project. They asked me to login into cluster and start work immediately. Can any one suggest me the steps to login?

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear what you're logging into. You should ask your coworkers for advice.

However, sounds like you have a Kerberos keytab, and you would run

```
kinit -k key.kt
```

There might be additional arguments necessary there, such as what's referred to as a principal, but only the cluster administrators can answer what that needs to be.

To verify your ticket is active

```
klist
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you will have Edge Nodes i.e client nodes installed with all the clients like

1. HDFS Client
2. Sqoop Client
3. Hive Client etc.

You need to get the hostnames/ip-addresses for these machines. If you are using windows you can use putty to login to these nodes by either using username and password or by using the `.ppk` file provided for those nodes.

Any company in my view will have a infrastructure team which configures LDAP with the Hadoop cluster which allows all the users by providing/adding your ID to the group roles.

And btw, are you using Cloudera/Mapr/Hortonworks? Every distribution has their own way and best practices.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming KT means knowledge transfer. Also the project document is about the application and not the Hadoop Cluster/Infra.

I would follow the following procedure:
1) Find out the name of the edge-node (also called client node) from your team or your TechOps. Also find out if you will be using some generic linux user (say "develteam") or you would have to get a user created on the edge-node.

2) Assuming you are accessing from Windows, install some ssh client (like putty).

3) Log in to the edge node using the credentials (for generic user or specific user as in #1).

4) Run following command to check you are on Hadoop Cluster:

```
> hadoop version
```

5) Try hive shell by typing:

```
> hive
```

6) Try running following HDFS command:

```
> hdfs dfs -ls /
```

6) Ask a team member where to find Hadoop config for that cluster. You would most probably not have write permissions, but may be you can cat the following files to get idea of the cluster:

```
core-site.xml
hdfs-site.xml
yarn-site.xml
mapred-site.xml
```